# Sending an unbuffered response in Plack

Tags: perl, uwsgi, plack, psgi

I'm working in a section of a Perl module that creates a large CSV response. The server runs on Plack, on which I'm far from expert.

Currently I'm using something like this to send the response:

```
$res->content_type('text/csv');
my $body = '';
query_data (
    parameters  => \%query_parameters,
    callback    => sub {
        my $row_object = shift;
        $body .= $row_object->to_csv;
    },
);
$res->body($body);
return $res->finalize;
```

However, that `query_data` function is not a fast one and retrieves a lot of records. In there, I'm just concatenating each row into `$body` and, after all rows are processed, sending the whole response.

I don't like this for two obvious reasons: First, it takes a lot of RAM until `$body` is destroyed. Second, the user sees no response activity until that method has finished working and actually sends the response with `$res->body($body)`.

I tried to find an answer to this [in the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Response) without finding what I need.

I also tried calling `$res->body($row_object->to_csv)` on my callback section, but seems like that ends up sending only the last call I made to `$res->body`, overriding all previous ones.

Is there a way to send a Plack response that flushes the content on each row, so the user starts receiving content in real time as the data is gathered and without having to accumulate all data into a veriable first?

Thanks in advance for any comments!

Comment: I did not try this, but you should be able to use an object with a `getline` method. For more detail, post a short but complete example.

Comment: Thank you Sinan. Yes, what you mention is correct, I tried a simple object implementing `getline` and it worked fine, except for the fact that Plack is still buffering the response and doesn't send anything to the browser until `->getline` is undefined. Regarding my example, I modified it to make it a little bit more self-explanatory. The only real difference by posting my real code would be a lot of non relevant lines added to the mix. The only thing I'm trying to figure out is how to make Plack send an unbuffered/autoflushed response.

Comment: There is no `get_data` function in your code. I think you mean `query_data`.

Comment: Posting a short but complete example enables you to reduce the work I have to do to try out possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use [Plack::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Response) because that class is intended for representing a complete response, and you'll never have a complete response in memory at one time. What you're trying to do is called streaming, and [PSGI supports it](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/PSGI/PSGI.pod#Delayed-Response-and-Streaming-Body) even if Plack::Response doesn't.

Here's how you might go about implementing it (adapted from your sample code):

```
my $env = shift;

if (!$env->{'psgi.streaming'}) {
    # do something else...
}

# Immediately start the response and stream the content.
return sub {
    my $responder = shift;
    my $writer = $responder->([200, ['Content-Type' => 'text/csv']]);

    query_data(
        parameters  => \%query_parameters,
        callback    => sub {
            my $row_object = shift;
            $writer->write($row_object->to_csv);
            # TODO: Need to call $writer->close() when there is no more data.
        },
    );
};
```

Some interesting things about this code:

- Instead of returning a `Plack::Response` object, you can return a `sub`. This subroutine will be called some time later to get the actual response. PSGI supports this to allow for so-called "delayed" responses.
- The subroutine we return gets an argument that is a `coderef` (in this case, `$responder`) that should be called and passed the real response. If the real response does not include the "body" (i.e. what is normally the 3rd element of the `arrayref`), then `$responder` will return an object that we can write the body to. PSGI supports this to allow for **streaming** responses.
- The `$writer` object has two methods, `write` and `close` which both do exactly as their names suggest. Don't forget to call the `close` method to complete the response; the above code doesn't show this because how it should be called is dependent on how `query_data` and your other code works.
- Most servers support streaming like this. You can check `$env->{'psgi.streaming'}` to be sure that yours does.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for this. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Plack is middleware. Are you using a web application framework on top of it, like Mojolicious or Dancer2, or something like Apache or Starman server below it? That would affect how the buffering works.

The link above shows an example by Plack's author:
https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/Plack-1.0037/eg/dot-psgi/echo-stream-sync.psgi

Or you can do it easily by using Dancer2 on top of Plack and Starman or Apache:
https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Manual.pod#Delayed-responses-Async-Streaming

Regards, Peter

Answer (score -2):

Some reading material for you :)

- https://metacpan.org/pod/PSGI#Delayed-Response-and-Streaming-Body
- https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Middleware::BufferedStreaming
- https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/Plack-1.0037/eg/dot-psgi/echo-stream.psgi
- https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/Plack-1.0037/eg/dot-psgi/nonblock-hello.psgi

So copy/paste/adapt and report back please